# Display data from MYSQL Database to Morris.js PHP AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, morris.js

I want to display the data from my database into a chart Morris.js to be precise. I need to choose a branch from my dropdown, when i choose a branch the total sales of that branch should be transferred to the Morris.js Bar chart. I am having a problem with transferring the data to the Bar Chart. I am using AJAX, PHP and Morris.js.

PHP Code for dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control" id="t-yearly">
    <option value="">Branch</option>
    <?php
        require_once "connect.php";

        $sql = "SELECT id,branch FROM tblLocation";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['branch']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

AJAX Code for chart display:

```
//Total Yearly Sales
$("#t-yearly").change(function(){
    var branch = $(this).val();
    $.ajax ({
        url:"fetch_yearly_sales.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {branch:branch},
        success: function(branch_data){
             new Morris.Bar({
                element: 't-yearly-sales',
                data: branch_data,
                xkey: 'year',
                ykeys: ['sales'],
                labels: ['Total Sales'],
                hideHover: 'auto'
             });
             console.log(branch_data);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP Code for fetch_yearly_sales.php:

```
<?php 
require "connect.php";


$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["branch"]);

$ar = array();

if(!empty($data)){
    $sql = "SELECT year, SUM(sales) AS sales FROM tblSales WHERE branch_id=".$data." GROUP BY year";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $ar[] = array(
            'year' => $row['year'],
            'sales' => $row['sales']
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($ar);
} 
else if (empty($data)){
    $sql = "SELECT year, SUM(sales) AS sales FROM tblSales GROUP BY year";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $ar[] = array(
            'year' => $row['year'],
            'sales' => $row['sales']
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($ar);
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is not working? You should start debugging in small steps, e.g. is your `fetch_yearly_sales.php` working? Test it with a REST web service tool or in the browser as a GET-request and change your php script to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: @xander I am debugging but still its not working the i choose a branch in the select box the chart is not appearing

Comment: So the `branch_data` you get in the AJAX response is that correct? just log it with `console.log(branch_data)`, it's hard to help as we can't run the code to test it in your case.

Comment: @xander this the data that inside the branch_data when you run my code [{"year":"2017","sales":"144185"},{"year":"2018","sales":"127828"}] The problem is that there is no visual representation of data

Comment: When I put your data in an Morris example chart it is displayed correctly I guess. see here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YeapoN

Comment: I tried to put the data manually it works flawlessly but when it is generated the chart and data is not working i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what problem you were experiencing, but from the code it looks like you're passing a JSON string to Morris, while it actually requires a JSON object. So try changing: `data: branch_data` to `data: JSON.parse(branch_data)`. I could be wrong though, it would help if you specified what exactly wasn't working.

Comment: can you edit my code? I am fiddling with this problem for two days now please help me

Comment: 1. I gave you a specific piece of code to change, if it doesn't work then we need more data, like what is the exact value of `json_encode($ar)` etc.

2. StackOverflow is not for writing code for you, we can help you improve your code by explaining why something doesn't work and giving instructions on (hopefully) how to make it work.

Comment: [{"year":"2017","sales":"144185"},{"year":"2018","sales":"127828"}] this is the data inside $ar

Comment: I didn't say that you write my code for me I meant, revise my code to fix my possible errors. I am just tired I am solving this problem for two days now. I really need help

Comment: So as I wrote in the answer: try changing: `data: branch_data` to `data: JSON.parse(branch_data)`.

Comment: The data of the chart is not changing. The flow of the site is when it is loaded, a chart will load with the sql that calculates the total sales of all the branches. Then, there is a select button that list down all the branches, when I choose a branch there is a sql the calculates the total sales of that specific branch. the problem is when i choose a branch there is no visual respresentation of data or the data is transferring to Morris.js

Comment: Did you try doing what I wrote? There is a difference between a JSON string and a JSON object.

Comment: @Ynhockey The result data should already be parsed as an JS object by jQuery when the data is encoded properly. But you can also try to set the correct header in your `fetch_yearly_sales.php` just add `header('Content-type: application/json');` before echoing JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to use the function *setData()* instead of creating a new chart always. This updates the chart with data given in parameters. You need to change to something like this:

```
var branch_data = [];
var my_chart = new Morris.Bar({
                element: 't-yearly-sales',
                data: branch_data,
                xkey: 'year',
                ykeys: ['sales'],
                labels: ['Total Sales'],
                hideHover: 'auto'
             });

$("#t-yearly").change(function(){
    var branch = $(this).val();
    $.ajax ({
        url:"fetch_yearly_sales.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {branch:branch},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(branch_data){
             my_chart.setData(branch_data);
        }
    });
});
```

By the way, I mentioned the dataType to JSON in the code above so that you would not need to parse the result from server.